# Что делать с метками относящимися к файлам?

Tags: обсуждение, метки

Сейчас на сайте есть три метки, которые обозначают файл(ы):

[file](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file) [files](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/files) и [файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)

Что делать?

P.S. Я предлагаю, либо оставить только метку [file](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file) и перенести в неё все вопросы с двух других, либо завести новую метку `файл` (все таки говорим по-русски) для всех вопросов из этих трех меток. Неиспользуемые метки удалить.

Comment: Нужно только вместе с этим добавить нормальное описание, чтобы было понятно, когда ожидается применение этой метки

Comment: Добавил варианты для упрощения голосования

Comment: @Nofate, удалите, пожалуйста, метку `arrays` в этом вопросе -> http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/450354/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8 Все заменил на `массивы`, там не могу.

Comment: Так как это не относится к теме обсуждения, это проще сказать в чате

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev, позор мне, но чатом я не пользовался ни разу :Р А обращение дойдет, думаю, до адресата.

Comment: @Visman приходите в чат!

Comment: В свете последних событий к этому вопросу нужно привлечь ещё немного внимания.

Answer (score 6):

Варианты ответов:

Удалить, так как это мета-метки.

Comment: голосую "за":  практически не представляю целевой поиск по этой мета-метке.  По моим наблюдениям: метки на нашем разделе SO в большей части наименование технологий.

Answer (score 3):

Варианты ответов:

Создать метку [файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb) для всех вопросов

Answer (score 2):

Ничего не делать.

На русском SO сейчас около 3 000 меток. На английском - 42 000 (а ведь у них точно такая предметная область + на русском еще 1C есть). Причем по метке [`file`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new/file) там есть описание и sponsored links. И 40 000 вопросов.

Разбирать левые метки руками, собирая под каждую консилиум на мете - пустая трата времени.

Comment: По идее за счёт меньшего размера сообщества ещё можно попробовать справляться со странными метками

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev можно,  но практической пользы в этом - никакой

Answer (score -1):

Варианты ответов:

Оставить метку [file](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file) для всех вопросов